# Call callback through 1 variable/object

Tags: c#, variables, callback, download

I work on a download system that downloads up to 4 files at once and if there is an error while downloading then it retries up to 5 times.
I would like it to call different callbacks with their variables once it finished downloading.

This is what I wrote:

```
private void Download(string url, (something) callback)
{
    if (asyncworkers++ < Global.paralleldownloads -1) // async download
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Proxy = (Global.proxymode == 2 ? new WebProxy(dynamicproxy) : (Global.proxymode == 1 ? new WebProxy(Global.proxy) : null));
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            timer.Enabled = true;
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => 
            {
                asyncworkers--;
                if (timer.Enabled)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    if (e.Error == null && e.Result.Length > 0)
                    {
                        AppendTextBox("successful async\r\n");
                        errors = 0;
                        //call "callback" and its variables here
                    }else{
                        AppendTextBox("empty async\r\n");
                        if (errors++ > 3)
                        {
                            //stop trying
                        }else{
                            Download(url, callback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
            timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                AppendTextBox("timeout async\r\n");
                timer.Enabled = false;
                client.CancelAsync();
                Download(url, callback);
            };
        }
    }else{ // sync download to delay it
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Proxy = (Global.proxymode == 2 ? new WebProxy(dynamicproxy) : (Global.proxymode == 1 ? new WebProxy(Global.proxy) : null));
        request.Timeout = 5000;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    if (data.Length > 0)
                    {
                        AppendTextBox("successful sync\r\n");
                        asyncworkers--;
                        errors = 0;
                        //call "callback" and its variables here
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        asyncworkers--;
        AppendTextBox("error sync\r\n");
        if (errors++ > 3)
        {
            //stop trying
        }else{
            Download(url, callback);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I would like to use it:

```
Download("http://.....", GetDataDone(var1, var2, var3, var4));
```

or

```
Download("http://.....", UpdateDone());
```

I hope the was I described it is at least a little bit clear to you. How could I get it working the way I wish? Thanks!

Comment: Read about lambdas/inline delegates. The syntax will be e.g. `Download ("...", () => UpdateDone ())`.

Comment: OK, in this case "callback" variable is "() => UpdateDone()". How do I call it from Download then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `callback` as `Action<T1,T2,T3,T4>` where `T1` is the type of `var1`, `T2` is `var2`, etc. Invoke the callback like this:

```
public void Download(string url, Action<T1,..> callback)
{
    //....
    callback(var1,var2,var3,var4);
    //...
}
```

Pass a function with matching signature **by name** as the callback or use a lambda to match the signature:

```
public void OnDownload(T1 var1, T2 var2, T3 var3, T4 var4)
{
     // do stuff here
}

//later
Download("http...", OnDownload);
```

**Update after comment**

Use a lambda expression to pass arguments upfront:

```
public void Download(string url, Action callback)
{
     //...
     callback();
     //..
}


 Download("http://..", () => OnDownload(42, "request", user, 0.5f));
```

Comment: "Download" should be able to call callbacks with 4, 0 or any other amount of parameters. Your solution is designed for 4 parameters only, right?

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it will be something with () => but I didn't know the exact way to write it.